# Pine script : Just text always on the corner top

Tags: pine-script

I would like to add text and keep it at the top right of the chart all the time.

It will be a sort of 4-line checklist.

This text is assigned to an indicator.

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here the problem of the col on the left side.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use table.new function.

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_table{dot}new](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_table%7Bdot%7Dnew)

```
//@version=5
indicator("table.new example")
var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 2, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Open is " + str.tostring(open))
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 1, row = 0, text = "Close is " + str.tostring(close), bgcolor=color.teal)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Works perfectly

Have a good day

Comment: Hi again,

Finally, i have a little problem with this code.

I have a col on the left side.

How can I remove this ?

Thanks

Comment: pls provide more info about problem